# Extracting text from URL with Index Split with URLs with different formats in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I need to get the text from URLs.

The formula INDEX(SPLIT(B3,"/",),"5")) works if the URL is formatted as a direct link.

However, if the URL is a redirect link it extracts "picassoRedirect.html" I need to use the formula RIGHT(INDEX(SPLIT(B3,"%",),"23"),10) if the URL is a redirect URL to get the text I want.

Is there a way I can combine both formulas and get the text in either case?

Comment: Welcome. Please read how to and [share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311) so as you can be easier helped.

Comment: Exact copy of [Extracting text from URL with Index Split with URLs with different formats](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/172541307).

Comment: What is text in `B3` cell?

Answer (score 0):

Use regexextract(), like this:

`=arrayformula( { "ASIN"; iferror( regexextract(B3:B, "dp(?:%2F|/)(\w+)") ) } )`

This array formula will fill a whole column in one go. Put the formula in cell `C2`.